# How to create a data analysis template (lavaan parameter table) using simsem package R?

Tags: r, montecarlo, r-lavaan

I am unfamiliar with simsem package for SEM simulations, and would like some help with it.

I would like to create a data analysis template (lavaan parameter table) for simulations with structural equation models and then perform simulation with real data.

I have found the example for this:

```
loading <- matrix(0, 9, 3)
loading[1:3, 1] <- NA
loading[4:6, 2] <- NA
loading[7:9, 3] <- NA
cfamodel <- estmodel(LY=loading, modelType="CFA", indLab=paste("x", 1:9, sep=""))

out <- analyze(cfamodel, HolzingerSwineford1939)

datamodel.nomis <- model.lavaan(out, std=TRUE)

output.nomis <- sim(1000, n=nrow(HolzingerSwineford1939), datamodel.nomis)
summary(output.nomis)
```

However, the creation of lavaan parameter table is a bit confusing (the definition of 'cfamodel' variable), especially, if for example exogenous variables or regressions are included in SEM model.

My SEM model is as per below. It includes 23 free parameters (5 factor loadings, 9 covariances between latent variable indicators, 3 regressions, 6 variances) and two defined (variance of the latent variable and indirect effect).

[graphical representation of SEM model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cECyY.png)

```
FullModel=
  "
# Latent variable definition
IWB =~ NOVE+EXPL+TEST+SUPP+IMPL

#Direct effects
IWB ~ OSE

#Medation
IWB ~ g*WE
WE ~ h*OSE

#Indirect effect
gh:=g*h

#Covariances
NOVE ~~ EXPL + SUPP + IMPL 
EXPL ~~ TEST + SUPP + IMPL
TEST ~~  SUPP + IMPL
SUPP ~~ IMPL 
"
```

As by the example I would start with:

```
loading <- matrix(0, 5, 1)
loading[1:5, 1] <- NA
cfamodel <- estmodel(LY=loading, modelType="CFA")
```

But then I have no idea, how to define the rest of the parameters?